# Get 500 error on update Pulsar schema of type "JSON" using admin API

Tags: http-status-code-500, apache-pulsar, pulsar

I am trying to update Pulsar schema of type "JSON" using [Admin API](https://pulsar.apache.org/admin-rest-api/?version=2.8.0&apiversion=v2#operation/postSchema).

I have a pulsar namespace "lol" and topic "sdf" with a single schema version
[List of topic schema versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FBd2.png)

I tried to update this schema by posting another JSON schema but received a 500 error.
[Post request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z5QA.png)

A Pulsar logfile is empty. Pulsar stack trace has nothing informative.

```
09:41:36.930 [BookKeeperClientWorker-OrderedExecutor-0-0] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLog - 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Jul/2021:09:41:36 +0300] "POST /admin/v2/schemas/public/lol/sdf/schema HTTP/1.1" 500 565 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8" 159
```

When I try to update the schema of type "AVRO" in the same way, everything works fine and the schema version rises up.

Can anybody help to find the cause of such weired behavior?

Here is request body

```
{"type": "JSON", "schema": "{  \"$id\": \"https://example.com/person.schema.json\",  \"$schema\": \"https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema\",  \"title\": \"Person\",  \"type\": \"object\",  \"properties\": {    \"firstName\": {      \"type\": \"string\",      \"description\": \"The person's first name.\"    },    \"lastName\": {      \"type\": \"string\",      \"description\": \"The person's last name.\"    },    \"age\": {      \"description\": \"Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.\",      \"type\": \"integer\",      \"minimum\": 0    }  }}", "properties": {} }
```

Here is the current schema definition "GET /admin/v2/schemas/public/lol/sdf/schema"

```
{
"version": 0,
"type": "JSON",
"timestamp": 0,
"data": "{  \"$id\": \"https://example.com/person.schema.json\",  \"$schema\": \"https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema\",  \"title\": \"Person\",  \"type\": \"object\",  \"properties\": {    \"firstName\": {      \"type\": \"string\",      \"description\": \"The person's first name.\"    },    \"surname\": {      \"type\": \"string\",      \"description\": \"The person's last name.\"    },    \"age\": {      \"description\": \"Age in years which must be equal to or greater than zero.\",      \"type\": \"integer\",      \"minimum\": 0    }  }}",
"properties": {}
```

Comment: You say you are updating a schema definition. Can you share the current schema definition, e.g., the output of the "GET /admin/v2/schemas/public/lol/sdf/schema" command?  Also, what command did you use to specify the current version of the schema?

Comment: @DavidKjerrumgaard I've updated my question with the current schema definition. I depend on the Pulsar version autoincrement. So version 0 for the current version of the schema was set automatically.